# jquery script on key to allow 2digit decimal, not negative and max 100

Tags: jquery, validation

Limit number between 0-100 and allow two digit decimal number.

```
    $(document).on('keyup','.percentage-value,#edit_value_percentage',function(e){
        if (e.keyCode != 9 || e.which != 9) {
        if (($.isNumeric(this.value) == false)) {
            this.value = '';
        }
        var val = parseInt(this.value);
        if (val != undefined && val != '') {
            if (val < 0)
                this.value = '';
        }
        }
        
   });
```

I have jquery function it allows numeric only

But need to allow two digit decimal value and should not exceed more than 100.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Need to limit value not more than 100 and allow decimal

Comment: Sorry, Is my  question still not understandable

Comment: you are almost there... insert `if (val>100)` in the appropiate place

Answer (score 0):

There are different between int and float in javascript int is full number like 1,2 and 3 where float is 0.1 => 100.0

**If you want to read more about int and float types:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

And what you are doing here I will try to explain

```js
if (e.keyCode != 9 || e.which != 9) { // listing for keyCode 9
    if (($.isNumeric(this.value) == false)) { // if its not a numbric (100 or 100.00)
        this.value = ''; // value set to '' you shut change it to -1.00 based on you question to work with float
    }
    
    var val = parseInt(this.value); // here you convert your variable to int its mean did you have a float her its will cut the decimal off, so use parseFloat and not parseInt

    if (val != undefined && val != '') { // val will never undefined or empty string becures we are working with floats and defined -1.00 if somthing are going wrong so inside here you need to check about its 0.00 or higher

        if (val < 0) // this if statement shut be remove, you will never go inside it at the first time.
            this.value = '';
        }
    }
}
```

hope my explantion help you to get better understading.

Comment: How to check two decimal value

Comment: it is allowing more than 2 decimal value

Comment: and allows more then 2 dots

Comment: you already check about its numbric with `$.isNumeric` and if its pass here you know its numeric, then you shut following my comments and you will convert it to float, if you did not know the different between int and float, i will recommend you to read up for data types before to go for the next step in your code.